# Rails attachment as attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope this question hasn't been asked before. 
I've got a rails app with a `places` model that has_many `pictures`. Pictures have images attached via paperclip and uploaded to imgur. This allows me to do this:

```
@place.pictures.last.image.url
```

That gets me an imgur link to my image.

My problem is that I want to access each place's pictures' urls directly in the object. Something like this:

```
@place = {
     id => 1
     title => "First Place"
     picture_urls => [imgur.com/link1, imgur.com/link2, imgur.com/link3]
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this at all. Via a migration? In my model file? I tried doing this in the controller:

```
@place.picture_urls = @place.pictures.each do |picture|
    urls = []
    urls.push picture.image.url
    urls
end
```

But strong parameters won't allow me to do that in the controller. Any help?

Maybe I should clarify further: Ultimately I want to pass @places to javascript to place them on a map and still be able to access each places pictures from the javascript object.

Comment: Can you not just do: `picture_urls = @place.pictures.map{|p| p.image.url}`?
This will give you array of all the picture urls for the `@place`: `[imgur.com/link1, imgur.com/link2, imgur.com/link3]` which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to access the place's pictures even when I call all pictures in a group with something like `@places = Place.where(title: "Test title")`

Comment: Where do you want to access/show this?

Comment: In your model, you can define a `picture_urls` attribute which will return the array of pictures of a given `place` anf then when you build your `@place` object, you can inject the `picture_urls` into that.

Comment: Right now only on a single view: `places#your_places`. The @places object will be passed to javascript via `<%= raw(@places.to_json) %>` in the view.

Comment: So, this `@places` is coming from a controller action right? And, it's a array of `@place` object, right?

Comment: Yes, `@places = Place.where(user_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94264/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-themainman).

Answer (score 0):

In your `Place` model, define `picture_urls` method:

```
# app/model/place.rb
def picture_urls
  self.pictures.map { |p| p.image.url }
end
```

Then, in your controller use this method:

```
def your_places
    @places = Place.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    temp_array = []

    @places.each do |place|
      temp_hash = {}
      temp_hash['id'] = place.id
      temp_hash['title'] = place.title
      temp_hash['picture_urls'] = place.picture_urls # use `picture_urls` method here
      temp_array << temp_hash
    end
    temp_array # this is the required data, array of place objects
end
```